# How to map model for NSManagedObject?

Tags: swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, clean-architecture, nsmanagedobjectmodel

When I try to do this, the model is stored in the NSManagedObjectContext if I use the context, and without it it throws an error, but I'm not expecting the same result.
Is there an easy way to implement this?

```swift
class WordDal: NSManagedObject {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<WordDal> {
        return NSFetchRequest<WordDal>(entityName: "WordDal")
    }

    @NSManaged public var word: String?
    @NSManaged public var uuid: UUID?
}

struct WordPresentation {
    let word: String
    let uuid: UUID
}

func mappingNSManagedObject(_ wordPresentation: WordPresentation) -> WordDal {
    let model = WordDal()
    model.uuid = wordPresentation.uuid
    model.word = wordPresentation.word
    return model
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should initialized a `NSManagedObject` always with a context. What's the error you got?

Comment: @Larme Does that mean I have no other choice? Unable to split model into layers?

Comment: @Larme -[Project.Word setUuid:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003edcfc0 (NSInvalidArgumentException)

Comment: That's strange. The error is saying that you are doing `someWord.uuid = ...`, while your code show `someWorkDal.uuid = ...`.  Are you sure about `model.uuid = wordPresentation.uuid` causing the crash?

Comment: @Larme Yep) But if it is, then when I map it - it will save the new model

Comment: "… without it it throws an error", compiler error or runtime error?

Comment: @Larme I added a screenshot of my case and where I noticed it

Comment: @Larme Next, I will replace the model that the function accepts

Comment: What is TranslationWord, an ordinary class or an NSManagedObject subclass?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson NSManagedObject subclass

Comment: Then please add the code for TranslationWord.init() and how uuid is declared

Comment: Not really, in your map(model:) function you do `let model = TranslationWord()`. That was the init I referred to.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson In this case I use an initializer NSManagedObject

Comment: Off topic but most of the code looks irrelevant, there is no need to make a copy of the object before removing it. since it is a custom init it would be interesting to see it but maybe there is no point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem like this (I don't know why I put it off and didn't understand right away):

```swift
class WordDal: NSManagedObject {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<WordDal> {
        return NSFetchRequest<WordDal>(entityName: "WordDal")
    }

    @NSManaged public var word: String?
    @NSManaged public var uuid: UUID?
}

struct WordPresentation {
    let word: String
    let uuid: UUID
}
```

```swift
func removeFromStorage(by uuid: UUID) {
    getDataFromStorage { [weak self] objects  in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        if let objectForRemove = objects.first(where: { $0.uuid == uuid }) {
        self.coreDataStack.mainContext.delete(objectForRemove)
        self.coreDataStack.saveContext(self.managedObjectContext)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm creating a presentation level model with UUID!
And I delete only on him himself UUID.
Now I can walk both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to redesign your model to have computed property for the new wrapper type that transforms the property value to and from the wrapper value.

Implementing a computed property in a Swift Core Data model is often a clear, more intuitive way to achieve what you need.

Here is an example implementation:

```
struct WordPresentation {
    let word: String
    let uuid: UUID }

class WordDal: NSManagedObject {
    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<WordDal> {
        return NSFetchRequest<WordDal>(entityName: "WordDal")
    }
    
    @NSManaged public var word: String?
    @NSManaged public var uuid: UUID?
    
    var wordPresentation : WordPresentation {
        get {
            return WordPresentation(word: self.word, uuid: self.uuid)
        }
        set {
            self.word = newValue.name
            self.uuid = newValue.id
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: But it only works in one direction. And how can I delete this model, for example?

Comment: By making the properties Optional and setting it to nil.